# "On which" or "upon which"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, american-english

Today, I am writing technical documentation that instructs the user how to install software to a server.  I encountered the following sentence and am unsure which is correct:

> When installing to a server other than that **on** which SQL Server is installed, ...

Should *on* be changed to *upon*?

> When installing to a server other than that **upon** which SQL Server is installed, ...

It all seems like a mouthful, but appears to be grammatically correct.

Comment: Saying that something is *upon* a server gives me the impression that it is sitting on top of the server. They are both grammatically correct, but only *on* conveys the proper meaning.

Comment: Good observation.  I believe the context of the sentence negates the association between "upon" and physical location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are indeed acceptable. I agree with Peter that *upon* kind of reminds me of something being within a physical relativity of the SQL server which is something I do not think you wish to convey to the user.

However, I would write

> When installing to a server *besides* the one on which the SQL Server is installed …

instead of

> When installing to a server other than that on which SQL Server is installed …

Comment: Good substitution!

Comment: I disagree with the substitution. "Besides" would be acceptable in a casual conversation, but for an instruction manual "other than that" has the proper register.

Answer (score 1):

(Little late, but for the record ...)
The best way to figure it out is to rephrase the clause as a sentence, i.e.:

*SQL Server is installed **on** another server.*

Using "upon" in that sentence would sound stilted.

Answer (score 0):

They're both acceptable. "Upon" is a little older and not used as much, certainly informally, as simply "on", but "upon" is still seen in technical and official documents.

The use of either preposition implies the figurative sense of a computer as a "platform" **on** which work can be done, documents can be placed, etc. You can also think of a computer, specifically its hard drives, as a "container" **in** which things are stored. In context, a person reading the document will almost certainly know that software is not installed by literally "putting it upon the computer" as in setting the disk on top of the computer case.

Comment: yes, somebody reading the document would almost certainly know what you meant if you used the proposition in, at, or onto, as well. That's not a good justification for using the wrong preposition. (I'm not totally convinced that *upon* is strictly incorrect, but *on* is much more frequent in this context.)

Comment: Very good observation.  However, I'm going with the substitution suggested by @Martha.

Answer (score 0):

*Upon* is a preposition that means *on* and it is especially used in abstract sense.

The NOAD has the following notes about *upon*:

> The preposition *upon* has the same core meaning as the preposition *on*. *Upon* is sometimes more formal than *on*, however, and is preferred in the phrases "once upon a time" and "upon my word," and in uses such as "row upon row of seats" and "Christmas is almost upon us."