# Use of "upon" or "on" in phrase

Tags: differences, prepositions

In a spiritual phrase the segment says

> ...have mercy **on** me, a sinner.

could you use "upon" rather than "on"?

I feel that using "upon" personalizes the phrase better.

Or is my grammar failing?

Comment: See related threads, [_“Based on” vs. “based upon”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/based-on-vs-based-upon), [_When to use 'Upon' instead of 'on'?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230401/when-to-use-upon-instead-of-on), [_Which is correct, on or upon?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/260541/which-is-correct-on-or-upon), [_Which phrase is correct: “dependent on” or “dependent upon”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25662/which-phrase-is-correct-dependent-on-or-dependent-upon/25666),

Comment: [_“The influence of … on/upon …”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8563/), [_On or upon + gerund_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27123/), [_“On which” or “upon which”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31913/), and [_Usage of “upon”_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7752/usage-of-upon).

Answer (score 2):

"**On**" and "***upon***" are interchangeable most of the time. Not always.

> He once wrote a book **on** Shakespeare's sonnets.

Can't use "upon" here.

***Upon*** sounds a notch more formal and can be a lot more emphatic, depending on the context.

There's some wild talk about "upon" only being used where actual physical space is involved, but it doesn't make much sense: "*Upon my honor*" is a perfectly legitimate phrase.

To confuse matters further, you can (and are encouraged to) use ***onto*** where both space and action are involved:

He climbed ***onto*** his horse.

Climbing **upon** one's horse is permissible, but climbing **on** does sound a bit comical (evoking, as it does, the image of a rider doing some climbing while already sitting on his horse).

Answer (score 0):

"'The Jesus Prayer' (Greek: Η Προσευχή του Ιησού, i prosefchí tou iisoú; Slotho d-Yeshu') or 'The Prayer' (Greek: Η Ευχή, i efchí̱ – literally "The Wish") is a short, formulaic prayer esteemed and advocated especially within Eastern [Orthodox] Churches:

'Lord Jesus Christ, Son of God, have mercy on me, the sinner.'”

From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Prayer

As such, I would not advise messing with it to make it more "personalized." But that is just my opinion, and you are free to change it as you please. Good luck!